# getservbyname failure error while trying to obtain thumbprint for OIDC

Tags: openid-connect, google-openid

Im trying to obtain the certificate for my OIDC IdP (google in my case) and want to download the certificate chain. I have installed and configured OpenSSL and retrieved the IdP's configuration document, using the following:

`https://server.example.com/.well-known/openid-configuration`

obviously replacing `server.example.com` with `accounts.google.com`

which returned the following:

```html
{
 "issuer": "https://accounts.google.com",
 "authorization_endpoint": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth",
 "token_endpoint": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token",
 "userinfo_endpoint": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo",
 "revocation_endpoint": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke",
 "jwks_uri": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs",
 "response_types_supported": [
  "code",
  "token",
  "id_token",
  "code token",
  "code id_token",
  "token id_token",
  "code token id_token",
  "none"
 ],
 "subject_types_supported": [
  "public"
 ],
 "id_token_signing_alg_values_supported": [
  "RS256"
 ],
 "scopes_supported": [
  "openid",
  "email",
  "profile"
 ],
 "token_endpoint_auth_methods_supported": [
  "client_secret_post",
  "client_secret_basic"
 ],
 "claims_supported": [
  "aud",
  "email",
  "email_verified",
  "exp",
  "family_name",
  "given_name",
  "iat",
  "iss",
  "locale",
  "name",
  "picture",
  "sub"
 ],
 "code_challenge_methods_supported": [
  "plain",
  "S256"
 ]
}
```

I am only interested in the value of the key `jwks_uri` which is `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs`

Now using the Uri from above I enter the following command in Terminal with hopes to retrieve the certificate chain:

`openssl s_client -showcerts -connect https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs:443`

which returns this ghastly, horrible, confusing, insulting response:

```html
getservbyname failure for //www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs:443
usage: s_client args

 -host host     - use -connect instead
 -port port     - use -connect instead
 -connect host:port - who to connect to (default is localhost:4433)
 -verify_hostname host - check peer certificate matches "host"
 -verify_email email - check peer certificate matches "email"
 -verify_ip ipaddr - check peer certificate matches "ipaddr"
 -verify arg   - turn on peer certificate verification
 -verify_return_error - return verification errors
 -cert arg     - certificate file to use, PEM format assumed
 -certform arg - certificate format (PEM or DER) PEM default
 -key arg      - Private key file to use, in cert file if
                 not specified but cert file is.
 -keyform arg  - key format (PEM or DER) PEM default
 -pass arg     - private key file pass phrase source
 -CApath arg   - PEM format directory of CA's
 -CAfile arg   - PEM format file of CA's
 -no_alt_chains - only ever use the first certificate chain found
 -reconnect    - Drop and re-make the connection with the same Session-ID
 -pause        - sleep(1) after each read(2) and write(2) system call
 -prexit       - print session information even on connection failure
 -showcerts    - show all certificates in the chain
 -debug        - extra output
 -msg          - Show protocol messages
 -nbio_test    - more ssl protocol testing
 -state        - print the 'ssl' states
 -nbio         - Run with non-blocking IO
 -crlf         - convert LF from terminal into CRLF
 -quiet        - no s_client output
 -ign_eof      - ignore input eof (default when -quiet)
 -no_ign_eof   - don't ignore input eof
 -psk_identity arg - PSK identity
 -psk arg      - PSK in hex (without 0x)
 -srpuser user     - SRP authentification for 'user'
 -srppass arg      - password for 'user'
 -srp_lateuser     - SRP username into second ClientHello message
 -srp_moregroups   - Tolerate other than the known g N values.
 -srp_strength int - minimal length in bits for N (default 1024).
 -ssl2         - just use SSLv2
 -ssl3         - just use SSLv3
 -tls1_2       - just use TLSv1.2
 -tls1_1       - just use TLSv1.1
 -tls1         - just use TLSv1
 -dtls1        - just use DTLSv1
 -fallback_scsv - send TLS_FALLBACK_SCSV
 -mtu          - set the link layer MTU
 -no_tls1_2/-no_tls1_1/-no_tls1/-no_ssl3/-no_ssl2 - turn off that protocol
 -bugs         - Switch on all SSL implementation bug workarounds
 -cipher       - preferred cipher to use, use the 'openssl ciphers'
                 command to see what is available
 -starttls prot - use the STARTTLS command before starting TLS
                 for those protocols that support it, where
                 'prot' defines which one to assume.  Currently,
                 only "smtp", "pop3", "imap", "ftp" and "xmpp"
                 are supported.
 -engine id    - Initialise and use the specified engine
 -rand file:file:...
 -sess_out arg - file to write SSL session to
 -sess_in arg  - file to read SSL session from
 -servername host  - Set TLS extension servername in ClientHello
 -tlsextdebug      - hex dump of all TLS extensions received
 -status           - request certificate status from server
 -no_ticket        - disable use of RFC4507bis session tickets
 -serverinfo types - send empty ClientHello extensions (comma-separated numbers)
 -curves arg       - Elliptic curves to advertise (colon-separated list)
 -sigalgs arg      - Signature algorithms to support (colon-separated list)
 -client_sigalgs arg - Signature algorithms to support for client
                       certificate authentication (colon-separated list)
 -nextprotoneg arg - enable NPN extension, considering named protocols supported (comma-separated list)
 -alpn arg         - enable ALPN extension, considering named protocols supported (comma-separated list)
 -legacy_renegotiation - enable use of legacy renegotiation (dangerous)
 -use_srtp profiles - Offer SRTP key management with a colon-separated profile list
 -keymatexport label   - Export keying material using label
 -keymatexportlen len  - Export len bytes of keying material (default 20)
```

I feel like the above code is my Yigrette and I'm still a naive Jon Snow, I still know nothing. Please help and forgive me if I can't see the obvious. I know nothing. Thanks everyone :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As SSL is an TCP-level protocol rather than HTTP, strip the protocol and path from the `-connect` to make that command work:

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect www.googleapis.com:443
```

However, what you are possibly after is the JWK Set that the OpenID Connect server publishes in its discovery document. This you can just retrieve and [analyse](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7517#section-5):

```
curl https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs
```

Then for each JWT you verify, extract the `kid` from its header and use it to look up the correct public key in the published set.

Comment: That worked like a charm, thanks Pieter! I just needed to trip the path :)